# JasperReport перевод на docx

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jasperreports

В проекте пытаюсь Hello World на docx перевести с помощью jasperReport

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f21add2e-088c-4fdd-8ed3-9a7a78986c9c">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="127" y="44" width="100" height="20" uuid="d97f55f6-b55e-407f-90b6-97067ead12db"/>
                <text><![CDATA[asdasd]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>

@Override
        public File printCard(BigDecimal id) throws Exception {
            File file = new File("NewExcel.docx");
            JasperReport report = getReport(new BigDecimal(1));
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null);
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, os);

                byte[] myReport = os.toByteArray();
                try (FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                    fop.write(myReport);
                    fop.flush();

                }
            }
            return file;
        }


private JasperReport getReport(BigDecimal id) throws JRException {
        JasperTemplate jasperReport = fillReport.findById(id);
        if (jasperReport != null) {
            try (InputStream jrXmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jasperReport.getJrxmlRus().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

                return JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrXmlStream);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

CbdFactory.printCard.query($scope.crud.data).$promise.then(
                    function (response) {
                        var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
                        anchor.attr({
                            href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(response),
                            target: '_blank',
                            download: 'filename.xlsx'
                        })[0].click();

                        notifyMessage("Успешно", "Данные успешно сохранены");
                        // $scope.getCardList();
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        restException(error);
                    }).finally(function () {
                    $scope.loading = false;
                });
```

в итоге получаю файл docx когда открываю он пишет что файл поврежден